# What word describes both survivors and decedents together?

Tags: single-word-requests

In statistics, specifically survival analysis, one often talks about the number of survivors *and* decedents in a cohort. What would be an appropriate word to describe the two groups?

Comment: Forgive me if it's a dumb question, but doesn't that include everyone in the cohort?

Comment: @thomas-francois: I thought so as well, but in these types of studies there is usually a third group; people who have dropped out of a study and are dealt with separately. As I understand it, this third group also forms part of the cohort.

Comment: Can you write a detailed example sentence where the word would be used?

Comment: What are they surviving (or not)? Are they victims of some event? If so, you can use *victims*.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The [APA Style](http://www.apastyle.org/learn/faqs/subjects-and-participants.aspx) site recommends the terms *participants* or *subjects*, noting:

> ...for more than 100 years the term *subjects* has been used within
>   experimental psychology as a general starting point for describing a
>   sample, and its use is appropriate.

So survivors, decedents, and dropouts as a whole constitute the initial *subjects* of the study; the survivors and decedents who remained are the *subjects* who are entered into the analysis.